# Error in signature generation on S3E air action script project

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, amazon-s3

Based on the Amazone s3 doc http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html
tried to create multipart upload and evertythinks works correctly until the last process "Complete Multipart Upload".

While posting the completed parts xml to amazon s3 to combine uploaded parts it gives error "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method".

```
public function getAuthenticationString(verb:String, dateString:String, resource:String, contentType:String = null, hash:String = null):String  {


        var toSign:String = verb + "\n";
        toSign += (hash != null) ? hash + "\n" : "\n";
        toSign += (contentType != null) ? contentType + "\n" : "\n";
        toSign += dateString + "\n" + resource;
        var toSignBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        toSignBytes.writeUTFBytes(toSign);          
        var hmacBytes:ByteArray = hmac.compute(secretAccessKeyBytes,toSignBytes);
        return Base64.encodeByteArray(hmacBytes);
    }
```

The error only shows when the last part is attempted to be sent to s3